# Derivative of $x^{1/3}$ where $x > 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anyone give me a hint on how to start with the problem below please?

Using the formal definition of a derivative, find $f '(x)$, where $f(x) = x^{ 1/3 }$ and $x>0$. You may use the fact that $a^3 - b^3$ = $(a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you need the epsilon-delta definition of the limit?

Comment: Does anyone know how to start with this problem?

Comment: You can trust that we, the above commenters, do. But it's better for you to show some of your work so we can deconstruct it.

Comment: To begin with, Kez, do you know the formal definition of derivative?

Comment: For $x>0$ and $h$ such that $x+h>0$ you have that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{(x+h)^{1/3}-x^{1/2}}{h}=\frac{(x+h)^{1/3}-x^{1/2}}{h}\frac{(x+h)^{2/3}+(x+h)^{1/3}x^{1/3}+x^{2/3}}{(x+h)^{2/3}+(x+h)^{1/3}x^{1/3}+x^{2/3}}=\frac{(x+h)-x}{h((x+h)^{2/3}+(x+h)^{1/3}x^{1/3}+x^{2/3})}$. Now, cancel the factor $h$ in the numerator with the one in the denominator and take the limit as $h\to0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^{1/3}-a^{1/3}}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^{1/3}-a^{1/3}}{(x^{1/3})^3-(a^{1/3})^3}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^{1/3}-a^{1/3}}{(x^{1/3}-a^{1/3})((x^{1/3})^2+x^{1/3}a^{1/3}+(a^{1/3})^2)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{(x^{1/3})^2+x^{1/3}a^{1/3}+(a^{1/3})^2}=\frac{1}{3}a^{-2/3}$